# Check if file exists before displaying in Magento PHP?

Tags: php, file, magento

I am able to get the web path to the file like so:

```
$filename = 'elephant.jpg';
$path_to_file = $this->getSkinUrl('manufacturertab');
$full_path = $path_to_file . '/' . $filename;
```

But if the file doesn't exist, then I end up with a broken image link.

I tried this:

```
if(!file_exists($full_path)) {
  Mage::log('File doesn\'t exist.');
} else {
  ?><img src="<?php echo $full_path ?>" /><?php
}
```

Of course that didn't work because `file_exists` does not work on urls.

How do I solve this?

1.) 
Can I translate between system paths and web urls in Magento?

e.g. something like (pseudocode):

```
$system_path = $this->getSystemPath('manufacturertab');
```

That looks symmetrical and portable.

or
2.)
Is there some PHP or Magento function for checking remote resource existence? But that seems a waste, since the resource is really local. It would be stupid for PHP to use an http method to check a local file, wouldn't it be?

Solution I am currently using:

```
$system_path = Mage::getBaseDir('skin') . '/frontend/default/mytheme/manufacturertab'; // portable, but not pretty
$file_path = $system_path . '/' . $filename;
```

I then check if `file_exists` and if it does, I display the `img`. But I don't like the asymmetry between having to hard-code part of the path for the system path, and using a method for the url path. It would be nice to have a method for both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Function

```
$localPath = Mage::getSingleton( 'core/design_package' )->getFilename( 'manufacturertab/' . $filename, array( '_type' => 'skin', '_default' => false ) );
```

will return the same path as

```
$urlPath = $this->getSkinUrl( 'manufacturertab/' . $filename );
```

but on your local file system. You can omit the '_default' => false parameter and it will stil work (I left it there just because getSkinUrl also sets it internaly).

Note that the parameter for getSkinUrl and getFilename can be either a file or a directory but you should always use the entire path (with file name) so that the fallback mechanism will work correctly.

Consider the situation

skin/default/default/manufacturertab/a.jpg

skin/yourtheme/default/manufacturertab/b.jpg

In this case the call to getSkinUrl or getFilename would return the path to a.jpg and b.jpg in both cases if file name is provided as a parameter but for your case where you only set the folder name it would return skin/yourtheme/default/manufacturertab/ for both cases and when you would attach the file name and check for a.jpg the check would fail. That's why you shold always provide the entire path as the parameter.

You will still have to use your own function to check if the file exists as getFilename function returns default path if file doesn't exist (returns skin/default/default/manufacturertab/foo.jpg if manufacturertab/foo.jpg doesn't exist).

Comment: Part of what I'm trying to do here is write code that will still work if I transfer the site to another server with a different file hierarchy. You're saying to use the full path in `$filename`, but where would I get that full path?

Comment: I did not say full path in $filename as in path from root of your file system. What I ment was that you should not write `$file_path = $this->getSkinUrl( 'manufacturertab' ) . '/' . $filename;` but instead you should write `$file_path = $this->getSkinUrl( 'manufacturertab/' . filename );` since this allows getSkinUrl function to not just check if folder but also if file exists. The same goes for getFilename function. Note that the path has not changed - the only thing that has changed is whether you concatenate the name and relative path from skin folder before or after you call the function.

Answer (score 3):

```
$fileUrl = $this->getSkinUrl('images/elephant.jpg');
$filePath = str_replace( Mage::getBaseUrl(), Mage::getBaseDir() . '/', $fileUrl);

if (file_exists($filePath)) {
  // display image ($fileUrl)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

it help me:

```
  $url = getimagesize($imagepath); //print_r($url); returns an array

    if (!is_array($url)) 
    {

                    //if file does not exists
    $imagepath=Mage::getDesign()->getSkinUrl('default path to image');

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use

```
$thumb_image = file_get_contents($full_path) //if full path is url

//then check for empty
if (@$http_response_header == NULL) {
  // run check
}
```

you can also use curl or try this link http://junal.wordpress.com/2008/07/22/checking-if-an-image-url-exist/

Comment: Thanks. I don't think I want to use HTTP methods though. It seems a waste when it is a local file. +1 anyway.

Comment: you can give localhost path

Comment: Yeah I guess if loopback is enabled, right? It still feels weird to use that when there is a local file. It does not seem like the right way to do it.

Comment: whwt warning you get?

Answer (score 2):

`Mage::getBaseDir()` is what you're asking for. For your scenario, `getSkinBaseDir()` will perform a better job.

```
    $filename = 'elephant.jpg';
    $full_path = Mage::getDesign()->getSkinBaseDir().'/manufacturertab/'.$filename;
    $full_URL=$this->getSkinUrl('manufacturertab/').$filename;

    if(!is_file($full_path)) {
      Mage::log('File doesn\'t exist.');
    } else {
      ?><img src="<?php echo $full_URL ?>" /><?php
    }
```

Note that for the `<img src>` you'll need the URL, not the system path. ... 
`is_file()`, rather than `file_exists()`, in this case, might be a good option if you're sure you're checking a file, not a dir.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following:

```
$file = 'http://mysite.co.za/files/image.jpg';
$file_exists = (@fopen($file, "r")) ? true : false;
```

Worked for me when trying to check if an image exists on the URL

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
namespace Your\Module\FileCheck;

use Magento\Framework\Filesystem;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\WriteInterface;

class ImagePath
{
    /**
     * @var WriteInterface
     */
    protected $mediaDirectory;

    public function __construct(
        Filesystem $filesystem
    ) {
        $this->mediaDirectory = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(DirectoryList::MEDIA);
    }

    public function checkImagePath()
    {
        $imagePath = '/catalog/product/placeholder/default/coming-soon.jpg';
        if ($this->mediaDirectory->isFile($imagePath)) {
            // code for file is available
        }
    }
}
```